# If mathematics has contradictions, will the entire mathematics be destroyed?

Tags: logic, axioms, foundations, peano-axioms

I know this question is very harsh to the mathematics community and so it is to me.

I have just started learning formal rigorous mathematics. I also heard of Godel's incompleteness theorem. I also know as of today, there are no mathematical contradictions even with millions of different mathematical theorems.

Nobody can tell if there is a contradiction or not. But if mathematics has contradictions, will the entire mathematics be destroyed?

$1+1=2$ can be proved using Peano axioms. Will its validity be also under question?

Every self evident axioms would turn out to be unreliable. Should we give them all up?

***Feel free to downvote if it hurts anyone. But please also explain the reason for downvote.***

Comment: NO. [Cantor and Dedekind's first *set theory*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-early/) was quite early proved to be inconsistent and we survived...

Comment: The truth of $1+1=2$ has been checked many many times counting apples and stones and babies...

Comment: I don't think that any downvote will be related to **hurting** someone. But this question might be *too broad* and *primarily opinion based*, and therefore eligible for "close flags" in some people's opinion.

Comment: I'll not downvote the question, but it is necessary to comment that it is simply **unanswerable**; it is like the pseudo-philosophical questions regarding the existence of the external world : "How can I be certain of it?" You can't.

Comment: We cannot have an "ultimate certainty" about it. What we need is a sort of *belidf* : do we like mathematics ? do we find it "useful" ? If yes, go on using it. D'Alembert, regarding the 18th century debate on the inconsistency of the *calculus* : "*Allez en avant, et la foi vous viendra* [go on and faith will catch up with you]."

Comment: Further to @MauroALLEGRANZA's point Scott d'Alembert, whatever contradictions may have existed in an early understanding of calculus have been removed by much the same process mentioned in my answer; calculus survived.

Comment: Peano's Axioms are pretty much bullet proof. In natural language, they are: (1) 0 is a natural number. (2) Every natural number has a unique successor. (3) Difference natural numbers have different successors. (4) 0 is not the successor of any natural number. It is the "first" natural number. (5) Every natural number but 0 can be reached by a process of repeated succession starting at 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have on occasion had to address contradictions. Erroneous assumptions about which properties of real numbers also applied to complex ones caused problems, but they were fixed by reframing these as proofs by contradiction that those properties didn't carry over. Later, Russell's paradox (as well as earlier but more advanced arguments) required more precise efforts to axiomatize set theory. So if something else goes wrong, we'll probably just delete or weaken an axiom somewhere. It would require starting from scratch on the proofs of some theorems, but it's such a rare event we can live with that.

Comment: AFAIK not even Russell's Paradox and its subsequent resolutions required much reworking of the mathematics of the day. Applications of mathematics by scientists (including Einstein and Maxwell)  as well as engineers were not affected at all

Comment: @DanChristensen That's because Maxwell was using calculus, not set theory. You can use set theory as a foundation for older mathematics, but that wasn't standard back then.